# Drive Realtime API no longer returns realtime document on localhost

Tags: google-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have been calling the following gapi javascript function with great success for a few months:

```
gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileId,
                         successHandler,
                         initializer,
                         errorHandler);
```

Suddenly, at 1:30 PM CDT today, that call stopped working when run in javascript on localhost.  I can deploy the exact same code to my server and it works perfectly!

Frustratingly, none of the callbacks are called - not successHandler OR errorHandler.

I have localhost:3000 set as an allowed javascript origin in my Google API Console project, and anyway I haven't changed any settings there since this was working.  I *am* correctly authorized and can make REST calls to the Drive API without an issue.

Has anyone else seen this behavior suddenly?  Can anyone from the Google team make a suggestion?

Update: the request inspector shows a GET to

```
https://drive.google.com/otservice/gs?access_token=[ommitted-for-stackoverflow]&id=[also-omitted]
```

with the response

```
)]}'
["17AKDsTY8kHESKfQavrHeh3YybD5k4b6ty8CQ78MHtyc","724b79b808d48070",false,1,[1,""],[0,[28,"724b79b808d48070","110581799581534438628",false,true,"REL DEV","#58B442","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/s128/photo.jpg"]]]
```

The headers are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length,Content-Type,X-Restart
alternate-protocol: 443:quic
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-disposition: attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 22:15:40 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: GSE
vary: Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-restart: 
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

There are no other requests after that.

Comment: Do you have any more detailed error information? Specifically, using the request inspector, can you determine whether the API is making an HTTP request to https://drive.google.com/otservice/gs? If so, what is the response from that URL?

Comment: Thanks Brian! I updated my question with some details.

Comment: OK, it looks like the API is loading the initial state properly, but the server -> client communication channel isn't connecting. What's odd is that this only happens locally - generally when there is a local/remote issue, it occurs because the URLs don't map correctly, but in this case there's no request at all which suggests an internal error.

Is there any way that I could access your development server to test this out, or would you be willing to share an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hey Brian, this problem has spread to our production server, so giving you access is not a problem :(.  If you have an @google.com email address you can install our app, "Pear Deck", from the Chrome Web Store, and create a new deck.  You'll be presented with an infinite loader and you can see the problem in the request inspector.  In the meantime I will try to make a minimal reproducing set.

Comment: So I've created a simple app that just creates a new drive file and loads the realtime document associated with it, and that is working fine, so I guess it's not some limit on my clientid.  Unfortunately I still don't know what is causing the problem, which you can still reproduce on our production server :(

Comment: Looks like the new relic client-side agent is an important piece of the puzzle.  My production servers are back to working after I removed the new relic piece, so that's a relief.  Will try to get you a working (broken) sample soon~

Comment: Ok, I have a working demo that shows that none of callbacks to the realtime document loader are called when new relic is running at the top. https://gist.github.com/rileylark/9992861  You'll need to supply your own google client id but the demo works even without valid new relic ids so you don't need to set that up.

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce the issue and I am looking into it now. One thing to note is that you are using a MIME type "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.pdk" - you probably want to use a "shortcut file" instead (see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file)

Comment: Hey Brian, FYI New Relic wrote me to say that they have ALSO reproduced the issue.  They think the problem is on their end and will be releasing a fix soon.